# Java HashSet key/value pair

Tags: java, iteration, hashset

Why doesn't Java provide functions to get the key/value pairs in a `HashSet` like exists in `Hashtable`? It seems like a real pain to have to iterate over it every time you need to get at something. Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean HashMap?  A HashSet does not contain key/value pairs.

Answer (score 11):

[HashSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) doesn't have key/value pairs. It is a [Set](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of objects and you would use an implementer of Set to ensure that a collection of objects contained no duplicates.

Implementers of Map like [HashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) have key/value pairs and provide a [get(Object key)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method to get the value associated with a key.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is starting to make sense.

Comment: Great. I remember I had the same confusion initially, I have found that I use Sets when I need to filter a bunch of objects down to unique objects only - in which case I usually then want to iterate over them and to stuff with them. I use Maps when I want to be able to look objects up by some value I'm using as a key.

Answer (score 2):

Since a `Set` doesn't contain keys and values, there is no way such a view could be provided.

What would you consider to be the key and what would be the value in a `Set`?

Comment: I guess I'm confused by the documentation: 
From Hashtable: "This class implements a hashtable, which maps keys to values. "
From HashSet: "This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). "
Seeing how HashSet is a HashMap and HashMap is similar to Hashtable, why is there no way to get at the key/value pairs?
If it is a question of uniqueness wouldn't overriding compareTo() be the way to go?

Comment: The HashSet is _backed_ by a HashMap, which means that internally it uses a HashMap. That however does not mean that it exposes the HashMap.

Comment: @Harley: As Robert said, the `HashMap` inside the `HashSet` is an implementation detail, it's not visible on the outside. Next: if you never **put in** a key/value pair, then what would you expect it to make visible?

Answer (score 0):

A `Set` don't have any key/value pairs, just (unique) values. As you already said you get these values via the `Iterator` or by returning an array with these values with the `toArray()` method.

Maybe you are looking for a `List` instead.